# optional POST parameter in spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editItem(String name, String description)
```

However, sometime description is not passed in (this is a simplified example than the real one), and i would like to make description optional, perhaps by filling in a default value if none is passed in.

Anyone have any idea how to do that?

thanks a lot!

Jason

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of using `@RequestParam` for the optional parameters, take a parameter of type `org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest`. For example,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editItem(
  @RequestParam("name")String name,
  org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest webRequest)
{
  String description = webRequest.getParameter("description");

  if (description  != null)
  {
     // optional parameter is present
  }
  else
  {
    // optional parameter is not there.
  }
}
```

Note: See below (defaultValue and required) for a way to solve this without using a WebRequest parameter.

Comment: better solution below!

Comment: different solution below (required = false)

Answer (score 128):

If you are using Spring MVC 3.0 or higher then just set `defaultValue` parameter of `@RequestParam`:

```
public ModelAndView editItem(@RequestParam(value = "description", defaultValue = "new value") String description)
```

In Spring MVC 2.5, I suggest to mark value as `required = false` and check their value against null manually:

```
public ModelAndView editItem(@RequestParam(value = "description", required = false) String description) {
    if (description == null) {
        description = "new value";
    }
    ...
}
```

See also [corresponding documentation about @RequestParam annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html).

---

**UPDATE** for JDK 8 & Spring 4.1+: now [you could use `java.util.Optional`](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/07/Spring41-and-Java8-Optional-as-RequestParam-RequestHeader-MatrixVariable.html) like this:

```
public ModelAndView editItem(@RequestParam("description") Optional<String> description) {

    item.setDescription(description.getOrElse("default value"));

    // or only if it's present:
    description.ifPresent(value -> item.setDescription(description));
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think this method is much cleaner than including the WebRequestParameter.

Comment: Also note that if your request parameter is a primitive (like int) and you mark it as required=false, you will want to use a wrapper class (like Integer) instead so that it can be passed as a null value to the controller method if the request parameter was not present.

Comment: This can be used for `@RequestHeader` as well!

Comment: The 'value = ' part is optional.