# How to give default date values in requestparam in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getSettlements", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
  public @ResponseBody
            Collection<Settlement> getSettlements
            (@RequestParam(value = "startDate") String startDate,
            @RequestParam(value = "endDate") String endDate,
            @RequestParam(value = "merchantIds", defaultValue = "null") String merchantIds)
```

How to give today's date in defaultValue ? It only takes constant.

Answer (score 21):

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final CustomDateEditor dateEditor = new CustomDateEditor(df, true) {
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            if ("today".equals(text)) {
                setValue(new Date());
            } else {
                super.setAsText(text);
            }
        }
    };
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, dateEditor);
}
```

---

```
@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "today") Date startDate
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `LocalDate`, you can create a default value like this:

```
@RequestParam(name = "d", defaultValue = "#{T(java.time.LocalDate).now()}", required = true) LocalDate d)
```

Comment: I like the solution with the SpEL.
Can you say what the `T` is doing here? Some kind of casting?

Comment: T( type ) creates an instance of the given type.

Answer (score 2):

I tried pretty much every option, even using interceptors. But from far the easiest solution was to use SpEL. For Example: defaultValue = "#{new java.util.Date()}"

Answer (score 0):

Since you receive a string you can any date format you want and later on use [*formatting*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) to extract the date

Comment: I want something like this @RequestParam(value = "merchantIds", defaultValue = date where date has been set up above as String date = new Date().toString();
     but its giving error "attribute value can only be constant"

Comment: You can add a private static String to the class and initialize it when the class loads and use it here.

Comment: thx for info.. I am doing the same .... priavte static String date = new Date().toString(); .... and using this date in my defaultValue but still its saying "attribute value can only be constant"

Comment: Try adding `final` in the parameter declaration

Comment: same error ..even after doing  private static final String date = new Date().toString();

Comment: On that case, try the following work-around: set the param to: `required = false` and in the code inside the method, check for `null` value and if so - compute it. See the following example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5639319/1057429

Comment: Yes i was doing the same but was trying to use defaultValue field someway.  Just i haven't added required=false .  Thanks for help.   Collection<SettlementItem> getSettlementItems
                (@RequestParam(value = "startDate",required = false) String startDate,
            @RequestParam(value = "endDate" ,required = false ) String endDate,
           
        {
                         if(startDate==null)
                            {
                                startDate=date;
                            }

Comment: Yes - that's exactly it!