# How to provide expression for @RequestParam's defaultValue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller where a RequestParam is used. Like this

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView process(
        @RequestParam(value = "startDate", 
                      required = false, 
                      defaultValue="yesterday()") startDate)
```

If the `startDate` is not specified a `defaultValue` is used. But in my case the value should be dynamic e.g. `now()` or `yesterday()`. Is there any way to specify an expression e.g. method of class to return the value?

I am too lazy to use code like this everywhere

```
startDate=startDate!=null ? startDate : new Date()
```

UPDATE
Ideally I would like to write custom expression to provide e.g. start of current week or end of current month if the date is not specified

Comment: so you want to populate default value dynamically?

Comment: @Braj the question has been updated

Comment: possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693435/how-to-give-default-date-values-in-requestparam-in-spring.

Comment: @Kakawait looks like really working solution. will try to adapt my code

Comment: @Kakawait could you post this as an asnwer so I can accept it. It works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explain here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22523299/636472:

You can handle your case by create a behavior for a special word:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final CustomDateEditor dateEditor = new CustomDateEditor(df, true) {
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            if ("today".equals(text)) {
                setValue(new Date());
            } else {
                super.setAsText(text);
            }
        }
    };
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, dateEditor);
}
```

---

```
@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "today") Date startDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The **defaultValue** has to be a `final static` expression. 
However there is a thing which you can do by using a custom annotation.

e.g.

create a custom annotation `@customAnno` apply this annotation to which ever methods you want.

using aspect `@before("@customAnno")` catch this method and check whether it have the value you want or you change the value you want at runtime.