# Sending many parameters to Spring MVC (all parameters are optional)

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Consider an application on top of Spring MVC, which shows the fields of a list of models in a table. You can filter table rows based on some conditions. Here's an example screenshot (taken from [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) issue tracking system, but it's immaterial to the rest of discussion):

[image: sample filters]

Now, notice that all filters are optional: I'm free to include / not include each filter in my search.
It is the job of the MVC controller to detect the presence/non-presence of filters in the request, and return the proper model (in conjunction with the ORM solution, which in my case is Hibernate).

The rather tedious process is for the controller to use a switch-case / if-else structure, to detect the presence/non-presence of filters in the request.

> Is there a better solution? For instance, is there a way for the controller to accept some object, where Spring (by proper configuration) maps the request to the fields of this object, and then the controller can properly pass this object to Hibernate to get the list of models?

For simplicity, please assume that we want to filter an "issue" table (as in the above picture), and "issue" model is the following POJO:

```
// for simplicity, annotations are removed
public class Issue {
    long id;
    Boolean status;
    float done;
    long author_Id; // foreign key

    //getters and setters
    ...
}
```

Comment: if i understand you correctly, `required=false` in your `@RequestParam` - or `Optional`, working with Spring 4.1 and Java 8 - might do the trick, like in Slavas answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571340/optional-post-parameter-in-spring-mvc or am i wrong?

Comment: @Dominik: Thanks a lot. It's a good approach to follow. My only concern is that I should manually construct the `where` condition of the filter, based on the presence of various items in the request (via calling `ifPresent()` API). I wish there were a simpler approach...

Comment: you might find what you're looking for (dynamic where-clauses) using the [Criteria](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/) API.

Comment: please feel free to accept the answer given by me below if it suits your needs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes, as stated in the comments, there's definitely a better solution for this.

Using current state technology (java8, spring 4.1+, criteria api), you could just use Java's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) - Container in your Controller. Using [isPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--), you could pass your arguments like this:

```
public void getResults(@RequestParam("filter") Optional<String> filter) {
    ...

    // or call a method only if filter is present:
    filter.ifPresent(value -> item.setFilter(value));

    //or a similar call via method reference
    //filter.ifPresent(this::setFilter);

    ...
}
```

To get the `where`-clause working with your dynamic filtervalues, I suggest using the [Criteria](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html)-API